# Help with restricted domain of a function to find inverse

Tags: inverse

Restrict the domain of $f(x)$ to find inverse:

\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^2+6x+9 = (x+3)^2 \\
g(x) & = \sqrt{x} - 3
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what **context** you encountered the problem, and what **your thoughts** on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ is not one-to-one on $\Bbb R$, so in order to find an inverse for $f$, you need to find a subset $D$ of $\Bbb R$ on which $f$ **is** one-to-one. The graph of $y=(x+3)^2$ is symmetric about the line $x=-3$. This means that values of $x$ equidistant from $-3$ have the same image under $f$: for any $a$,

$$f(-3+a)=\big((-3+a)=3\big)^2=a^2=(-a)^2=\big((-3-a)+3\big)^2=f(-3-a)\;.$$

Thus, $D$ cannot contain both $-3+a$ and $-3-a$ for any $a$. The simplest ways to arrange this are to take $D$ to be either $$[-3,\to)=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ge -3\}\tag{1}$$ (also written $[-3,\infty)$) or $$(\leftarrow,-3]=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\le -3\}\tag{2}$$ (also written $(-\infty,-3]$).

$$D=[-3,\to)=\{x\in\Bbb R:x\ge -3\}\;.$$

Now go back to $y=(x+3)^2$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$: $x+3=\pm\sqrt y$, and $x=\pm\sqrt y-3$. If we choose the positive square root, we get the function $g(x)=\sqrt x-3$; if we choose the negative square root, we get the function $h(x)=-\sqrt x-3$. Each of these is an inverse of $f$ on some domain, and it’s not hard to check that $g$ goes with the domain $(1)$ and $h$ with the domain $(2)$: for any $x\ge 0$, $g(x)=\sqrt x-3\ge-3$ and $h(x)=-\sqrt x-3\le-3$.

In most contexts it’s more natural to choose the function $g$ and the domain $(1)$: the function $g(x)=\sqrt x-3$ is the inverse of the restriction of $f$ to the domain $[-3,\to)$.